# How to compare dates in multiple tables sql query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, qsqlquery

Pleas have look at my tables and queries and data retrieving scenario.
i am failing to compare/check the dates  between with from to another tables.
my logic is to get the incidents logged between from and To dates of a contracts(It should be between effective & Expiry date of that contract)

```
Table:Incident:
+-------------+-------------+---------+
| incident_id | date_logged | item_id |
+-------------+-------------+---------+
|    10074329 | 2015-09-01  |   63247 |
|    10074869 | 2016-01-31  |   63247 |
|    10074399 | 2016-01-20  |   63247 |
|    10075274 | 2016-02-07  |   63247 |
|    10035727 | 2013-08-02  |   47558 |
|    10050239 | 2014-07-08  |   47558 |
|    10076340 | 2016-02-25  |   47558 |
+-------------+-------------+---------+

Table:Item:
+---------+-------------+
| item_id |   item_sc   |
+---------+-------------+
|   63247 | 313150069   |
|   47558 | 2S27500EVW  |
+---------+-------------+
Table:item_maint
+---------------+---------+---------------+-------------+-------------+
| item_maint_id | item_id | maint_crct_id | start_date  |  end_date   |
+---------------+---------+---------------+-------------+-------------+
|           701 |   63247 |          2132 | 2015-11-11  | 2016-11-10  |
|           702 |   63247 |          1819 | 2014-11-11  | 2015-11-10  |
|           703 |   47558 |           921 | 2013-05-01  | 2016-09-08  |
+---------------+---------+---------------+-------------+-------------+
Table:maint_crct
+---------------+-----------------+----------------+-------------+
| maint_crct_id |  maint_crct_sc  | effective_date | expiry_date |
+---------------+-----------------+----------------+-------------+
|          1819 | ACSS-2015-0011  | 2014-11-11     | 2015-11-10  |
|          2132 | ACSS-2015-0091  | 2015-11-11     | 2016-11-10  |
|           921 |  ACSS-2013-0066 | 2013-05-01     | 2016-09-08  |
+---------------+-----------------+----------------+-------------+
```

My Query:

```
Declare @contract varchar(50); set @contract='ACSS-2015-0011'
declare @from date;set @from='2014-01-01'
declare @To date; set @To='2015-09-01'
select  dbo.incident.incident_id,dbo.incident.date_logged,dbo.item.item_id,
 dbo.item.item_sc,dbo.maint_crct.maint_crct_id, dbo.maint_crct.maint_crct_sc
FROM dbo.incident INNER JOIN
dbo.item ON dbo.incident.item_id = dbo.item.item_id INNER JOIN
dbo.item_maint INNER JOIN  dbo.maint_crct ON dbo.item_maint.maint_crct_id = 
dbo.maint_crct.maint_crct_id
ON dbo.incident.item_id = dbo.item_maint.item_id    
WHERE dbo.maint_crct.maint_crct_sc=@contract
```

How to add @from and @To date in WHERE clause to check the logged_dates in between effective_date & expiry_dates of maint_crct table.

```
Expected Result:
+-------------+-------------+---------+-----------+---------------+----------------+
| incident_id | date_logged | item_id |  item_sc  | maint_crct_id | maint_crct_sc  |
+-------------+-------------+---------+-----------+---------------+----------------+
|    10074329 | 2015-09-01  |   63247 | 313150069 |          1819 | ACSS-2015-0011 |
+-------------+-------------+---------+-----------+---------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: You're going to have to do a better job of explaining the logic behind your expected results.  That last paragraph before "Expected Result:" doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @TabAlleman : my logic is to get the data from incidnet table logged between from and To date of a contract and need to be compare the dates should be between effective and expiry date of that contract. Thanks

Comment: Ok, then my answer below should cover it.   If you make the attempt and don't get your expected result, please edit your question with your new query so we can debug it.

Comment: @TabAlleman Thanks for ur advice i have added script in WHERE clause "and dbo.item_maint.start_date <= dbo.maint_crct.expiry_date and dbo.item_maint.end_date >= dbo.maint_crct.effective_date" but not geting the real answer .. thanks again

Comment: What result are you getting with that change to the WHERE clause?

Answer (score 0):

You can compare dates with any of these operators, all of which are documented in MSDN:  `<` `>` `<=` `>=` `BETWEEN`

Since the SQL you posted in your question doesn't make any attempt at doing this, I'm assuming that's the part you're stuck on.

Comment: My question is , How to retrieve incident under "contract" of an item logged between "From" and "To" dates and it need to check the dates(from & To) are in between the "Contract's" effective and expiry dates...  thanks.